# Sort by Object property and then append specific object to end of array within an Object of nested Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the following Object with nested Arrays of Objects.

I am trying to write a simple Javascript function to sort the objects within those arrays alphabetically by the "label" property and then push the object with the label "other" to the end of that Array.

Here is my current solution, but I am wondering if there is a cleaner, more declarative way to approach this solution?

https://jsfiddle.net/3fjq50Lb/

```
let things = {
  "animals": [{
      "id": 0,
      "label": "cat"
    },
    {
      "id": 100,
      "label": "Undefined"
    },
    {
      "id": 200,
      "label": "turtle"
    },
    {
      "id": 300,
      "label": "Other"
    },
  ],
  "colors": [{
      "id": 0,
      "label": "yellow"
    },
    {
      "id": 100,
      "label": "green"
    },
    {
      "id": 200,
      "label": "red"
    },
    {
      "id": 300,
      "label": "blue"
    }
  ]
}

let sortedThings = {};
Object.entries(things).forEach((entry) => {
  let key = entry[0];
  let otherOption = entry[1].filter((o)=> o.label === "Other");
  console.log(otherOption)
  let vals = entry[1].sort((a, b) => (a.label > b.label) ? 1 : ((b.label > a.label) ? -1 : 0)).filter((s) => s.label !== "Undefined")
  if(otherOption.length){
     vals = vals.filter((s) => s.label !== "Other");
     vals = vals.concat(otherOption);
  }
})
```

Comment: Please post your code with the `Object.entries()` iteration even if it doesn't work, we cannot help you with fixing it otherwise.

Comment: @Bergi -- I've updated with my current solution

Comment: "*I am having difficulty returning a new Object with those stringed keys*" - all you seem to be missing is a `sortedThings[key] = vals;` at the end of the iteration.

Answer (score 0):

It can be optimized as follows:

1. Remove the "Undefined" value first, so it doesn't slow down the sorting.
2. During sorting, forcibly define "Other" as the larger item to move it to the end of the array.

```js
const things = {
  "animals": [{
      "id": 0,
      "label": "cat"
    },
    {
      "id": 100,
      "label": "Undefined"
    },
    {
      "id": 200,
      "label": "turtle"
    },
    {
      "id": 300,
      "label": "Other"
    },
  ],
  "colors": [{
      "id": 0,
      "label": "yellow"
    },
    {
      "id": 100,
      "label": "green"
    },
    {
      "id": 200,
      "label": "red"
    },
    {
      "id": 300,
      "label": "blue"
    }
  ]
};

const sortedThings = Object.entries(things).reduce((obj, [key, value]) => 
    (obj[key] = value
        .filter(item => item.label != "Undefined")
        .sort((a, b) => (
            a = a.label.toLowerCase(), 
            b = b.label.toLowerCase(), 
            a == b ? 0 : b != "other" && (a == "other" || a > b) ? 1 : -1
        )), 
        obj
    ), 
{});

console.log(sortedThings);
```